# Read STDIN line by line in PHP

Tags: php

I want to do something like this:

```
1,abc,100
2,xyz,200
3,uyx,300
4,sje,400
5,tek,500
```

if I pass this input to PHP it is reading the first line and the stream gets closed immediately. I want to read/write all lines and stream should be open all time.Almost like using a stream with a timeout.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
<?php
$rk = new RdKafka\Producer();
$rk->setLogLevel(LOG_DEBUG);
$rk->addBrokers("localhost:9092");
$topic = $rk->newTopic("testing");
$temp = fopen("php://stdin","r");
$line = fgets($temp);
$foo = rtrim($line);
$topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA,0,$foo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected. You are doing just one `fgets()` so this is what you will get. [Docs read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php):

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which
>   is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first)

If you want to to read more you need to loop:

```
while (!feof($temp)) { 
    $line = rtrim(fgets($temp));
    $topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, $line);
}
```